# How to recover a file with volatility from a linux profile

Tags: linux, forensics, intrusion, volatility, bulk-extractor

I'm trying to recover files from a .mem file with volatility. The mem file is from a Linux machine. I have already loaded the profile and it works fine. I have discovered that the drupalgeddon2 vulnerability was exploited but I need evidence.

To get that evidence I tried the volatility module linux_enumerate_files to enumerate all the files and look for the ones that could be malicious. I found some weird files in the /tmp folder and need to recover them, or at least the hash so that I can check in Virustotal if they are malicious.

To recover the files I tried the module linux_find_file like this:

```
python2 vol.py --profile=Linuxperfil_memoria_volatility2x64 -f /media/sf_drive-download-20230328T154924Z-001/memoria.bin linux_find_file -F "/tmp/kKUKJsTYJHOVIjKIXYg7wqlj0.php" -O ../Desktop/shell
```

But the output is:

```
Inode Number                  Inode File Path
---------------- ------------------ ---------
----------------                0x0 /tmp/kKUKJsTYJHOVIjKIXYg7wqlj0.php
```

And the file shell is not created. I guess the reason volatility can't recover the file and store it in "shell" is because the file doesn't have an inode number, but I don't really know.

Is there any way I can recover this file with volatility?

PD: I also tried bulk_extractor, and it created a folder named "utmp_carved", with hashes and a lot of entries but there are no names, so I don't know what file I am actually looking for. If there is any way that I can recover the file or its hash this way instead of using volatility I could use it too.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Let's start from the start - did you download and use the same kernel used as in the image? Keep in mind that kernels only up to 5.5 are supported according to the documentation.

Comment: Please refer to the documentation like https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility/wiki/Linux If you prefer to use vol.py 3 which is strongly recommended please check out https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility3

Comment: It is a college project so I have to use volatility 2 and the teacher give me the image so I guess there isn't any version problem

Comment: Did you download the kernel symbols as written in the documentation?

Comment: I dind.t downlad anything, I am not creating a profile, I am just trying to analyze a given memory with a given profile and the volatility2. Is there any way to recover a deleted file?

Comment: Please follow the documentation...

Comment: Please, if you are not going to contribute anything of value, do not act as if you know what you are talking about. I found out that it is not possible to recover this file, so please enlighten me, what documentation?

Comment: You're probably missing some symbols which are used for (remotely any) use case. You should read the initial setup steps as denoted in the documentation... If you did that already maybe try Vol3.py? I know what you've been told, but if you need to solve a problem...

Comment: Ok, with the details provided in the comments ("I found out that it is not possible to recover this file") then this question is unanswerable. Please don't berate people trying to help you when 1. we don't have the file and we're working with partial information, and 2. it turns out the problem was unsolvable from the start.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was unsolvable.

Comment: I just asking for help, not for somebody telling me en different comments just to read the documentation. I know I have to read it, and I already did. I am not just some newby with no idea who you can just pretend to help....

Comment: The question can be close without problem.